AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'
I was given a document that I run in Jupyter through Anaconda Navigator.  The person who created the code is gone, and I am stuck.  For over a year it was running fine daily.  A couple of weeks ago Anaconda stopped working so IT reinstalled with the latest version.  However, since then the document keeps failing at a certain part.  I can continue on, but this portion does not produce the needed results.  The code is below.  Do I need to edit the code to prevent the error?  I appreciate any help available.
productivity_flname = "%s/productivity_%s.xlsx" %(expath, fsuffix)
with pd.ExcelWriter(productivity_flname) as writer:
    prod_book = writer.book
    prod_info_sheet = prod_book.add_worksheet('Info')
    prod_info_sheet.insert_textbox('A1', productivity_txt_bx, txt_bx_options)
    for row, data in enumerate(['Adjudicators'] + adjudicators):
        prod_info_sheet.write_string(row, 12, data)  
    for row, data in enumerate(['Peer Reviewers'] + peer_reviewers):
        prod_info_sheet.write_string(row, 13, data)
    prod_info_sheet.set_column("M:N", 18)    
    adj_ret.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="All Adjudicators", index = True)
    review_ret.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='All Peer Reviewers', index = True)
    for nm in adjudicators:
        print(nm)
        write_individuals(adj_ret, nm)
    for nm in peer_reviewers:
        print(nm)
        write_individuals(review_ret, nm)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 7
      6 prod_book = writer.book
----> 7 prod_info_sheet = prod_book.add_worksheet('Info')
      8 prod_info_sheet.insert_textbox('A1', productivity_txt_bx, txt_bx_options)

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_worksheet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 5
      1 ### write the report to an excel file
      2 ### as data for individual adjudicators and peer reviewers is written to the excel file, their names will appear below
      4 productivity_flname = "%s/productivity_%s.xlsx" %(expath, fsuffix)
----> 5 with pd.ExcelWriter(productivity_flname) as writer:
      6     prod_book = writer.book
      7     prod_info_sheet = prod_book.add_worksheet('Info')

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1322, in ExcelWriter.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
   1316 def __exit__(
   1317     self,
   1318     exc_type: type[BaseException] | None,
   1319     exc_value: BaseException | None,
   1320     traceback: TracebackType | None,
   1321 ) -> None:
-> 1322     self.close()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py:1326, in ExcelWriter.close(self)
   1324 def close(self) -> None:
   1325     """synonym for save, to make it more file-like"""
-> 1326     self._save()
   1327     self._handles.close()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py:109, in OpenpyxlWriter._save(self)
    105 def _save(self) -> None:
    106     """
    107     Save workbook to disk.
    108     """
--> 109     self.book.save(self._handles.handle)
    110     if "r+" in self._mode and not isinstance(self._handles.handle, mmap.mmap):
    111         # truncate file to the written content
    112         self._handles.handle.truncate()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py:407, in Workbook.save(self, filename)
    405 if self.write_only and not self.worksheets:
    406     self.create_sheet()
--> 407 save_workbook(self, filename)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:293, in save_workbook(workbook, filename)
    291 archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
    292 writer = ExcelWriter(workbook, archive)
--> 293 writer.save()
    294 return True

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:275, in ExcelWriter.save(self)
    273 def save(self):
    274     """Write data into the archive."""
--> 275     self.write_data()
    276     self._archive.close()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py:89, in ExcelWriter.write_data(self)
     87 writer = WorkbookWriter(self.workbook)
     88 archive.writestr(ARC_ROOT_RELS, writer.write_root_rels())
---> 89 archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, writer.write())
     90 archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK_RELS, writer.write_rels())
     92 self._merge_vba()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:148, in WorkbookWriter.write(self)
    146 self.write_names()
    147 self.write_pivots()
--> 148 self.write_views()
    149 self.write_refs()
    151 return tostring(self.package.to_tree())

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:135, in WorkbookWriter.write_views(self)
    134 def write_views(self):
--> 135     active = get_active_sheet(self.wb)
    136     if self.wb.views:
    137         self.wb.views[0].activeTab = active

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py:33, in get_active_sheet(wb)
     31 visible_sheets = [idx for idx, sheet in enumerate(wb._sheets) if sheet.sheet_state == "visible"]
     32 if not visible_sheets:
---> 33     raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
     35 idx = wb._active_sheet_index
     36 sheet = wb.active

IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible

Usually this portion of the code will create an Excel workbook with multiple tabs.  The first tab is just an info page, then a couple of cumulative tabs, and then individual breakdowns of the provided data.  Overall, the whole document creates 5 different workbooks.  I am just getting this error on this section and then again on another with the same error.
Example of code that is still working.
    bpo_prod_fl = "%s/bpo_productivity_map_%s.xlsx" %(expath, fsuffix)
with pd.ExcelWriter(bpo_prod_fl) as writer:
    bpo_case_map.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'normal workflow')
    bpo_out_map.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'outside of workflow')
    bpo_activity_all.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'all activity')
    for bpo_start in bpo_out_starts:
        bpo_tmp = bpo_out_workflow[bpo_out_workflow['old_value'] == bpo_start]
        bpo_out_ret = bpo_tmp[['old_value', 'new_value', 'edited_by', 'date_edited', 'case_number']]
        bpo_out_ret.sort_values(['old_value', 'edited_by'], inplace = True)
        bpo_out_ret.set_index(['old_value', 'edited_by'], inplace = True)
        bpo_out_ret.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = bpo_start[:30], index = True, merge_cells = True)


Please [edit] your question and format the code as code (use the {} button). Make sure it's a [mcve] that people can copy & paste. Currently the indentation is all off. That said, looks like your dependency upgrade brought in an incompatible version of the Excel libraries. You'll need to check the documentation of the version you are using on how to call it.

Sorry about the format error.  I hope I fixed that.  It appears the version I have installed is 23.7.4 so I will look further into that now.  Thank you for the advice.

Actually, the specific Python version looks to be 3.11.5

pandas.ExcelWriter uses xlsxwriter if it is installed, otherwise openpyxl.  Your code is assuming the use of xlsxwriter (for example, .add_worksheet() only exists in that package), but you're getting an error from openpyxl.  I would assume that xlsxwriter didn't get reinstalled.

Hmm, what is weird though is that some of the Excel files are created without issue.  I did note that the 2 files that have broken had an "Info" sheet to start with that described the rest of the tabs, while the ones still working just had multiple tabs of data.  I was going to attempt to remove the info pieces to see if that helped.  I will add an example of the code that is working.
